# How do I reduce the running time of my program?

Tags: c

I was solving a problem on HackerEarth but as I submitted my solution most of the test cases were passed and the rest showed 'Time Limit Exceeded'. I would be very grateful if you could help me improve the algorithm of my code to reduce the runtime.

**Following is the problem:**
Alice works as a restaurant manager. The restaurant has prepared 'N' lunch boxes and Alice plans to distribute them to some schools. Consider that there are 'M' schools and an i-th school orders `A[i]` lunch boxes.

She wants to distribute lunch boxes to as many schools as possible. Also, she has the following rule:

For an i-th school, she gives either zero or `A[i]` lunch boxes

Your task is to help Alice to determine the maximum number of schools that can get lunch boxes.

**My code-**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while (t--) {
        int n, m;
        scanf("%d", &n); 
        scanf("%d", &m); 
        int a[m];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            scanf("%d", &a[i]);   
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < m; j++) {
                if (a[i] > a[j]) {
                    int temp = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[j];
                    a[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
       
        int sum = 0, count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            sum = sum + a[i];
            if (sum > n) {
                break;
            } else {
                while (sum <= n) {
                    count++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n", count);
    }
}
```

Comment: forgot to mention that I have used variable t for the number of test cases

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it would be more appropriate for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Iguananaut: I don't agree: there is a bug in the code, the output is incorrect.

Comment: Your code is flawed: your method to compute `count` seems incorrect. You should just return `i` when the sum exceeds `n`: `if (sum > n) return i;`

Comment: @chqrlie Fair enough, though they didn't say if it actually worked or not.  I assumed it did but was just slow.

Comment: Also: `while (t--) {` -> `while (t --> 0) {`

Comment: Another idea: use `qsort()` to sort the array instead of your insertion sort variant with quadratic complexity.

Comment: @Iguananaut: actually, the `while (sum <= n) { count++; break; }` looks bogus but is fully redundant and equivalent to `count++;` The problem is probably just the quadratic sort complexity.

Comment: @Iguananaut may I know why this question is not appropriate for this forum?

Comment: It's not too bad (voted to reopen), but maybe walk us through your algorithm and state its time complexity, ideas you might have for optimizing it to avoid it sounding like a "here's my code. fix it for me"-type question. Thanks.

Comment: If it fails on time limit, then you did not produce an answer at all. They abort the program when the time limit is reached. Note that these competition sites aren't just about solving the problem, but finding an *efficient* way to solve the problem: it's part of the task. Apart from any coding errors, if someone here has a good solution they probably aren't going to give it to you, but submit it themselves.

Comment: @ggorlen I didn't mean my question to come off like that, I tried several ways to improve the complexity (tried to reduce some loops) but I am out of ideas, I just needed suggestions from the 'experts'.

Comment: I realize you didn't, but to some "experts" it does come off like that, so it's up to you to show what you've tried specifically. Something like "my solution approach is to distribute lunches to each school using foobar which I realize is O(nn). I thought that if garply then I could reduce the time complexity to O(n log(n)) but it fails to account for corge". I'm making it up, but you get the idea. With this sort of walkthrough, people will be much more receptive to answering. And we know you're out of ideas and need help--that's true for all posts here pretty much.

Comment: One way is not to run the program. But on a serious note put the sum calculation in the for loop reading the numbers.

Comment: @EdHeal: computing the sum as you read the numbers does not work in the general case because you need to determine which schools to omit. A simple method for this is to sort the schools by order size and deliver those with the smallest orders. Granted one could store the orders in a sorting structure as them come, it is much simpler to collect them in an array and sort the array.

Comment: @chqrlie - But you have `n` and `a[i]` so should be able to compute `sum` in the reading loop

Comment: @EdHeal: there is a misunderstanding: `sum` is not the sum of all entries, it is computed after sorting the entries as the sum of the lowest orders, to test how many can be delivered without exceeding `n`. Computing it during the read phase would be meaningful only if all orders can be delivered, thereby avoid the costly sort phase, but it does not seem necessary to implement this optimisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final loop should be simplified: the `while (sum <= n) { count++; break; }` is fully redundant and equivalent to `count++;`.

You can simply use `i` at the end of the loop:

```
    int i;
    int sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        sum = sum + a[i];
        if (sum > n) {
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", i);
```

Regarding the time limit, it is possible that the test cases use large amounts of data, and the sort method you use has quadratic time complexity **O(m<sup>2</sup>)**, causing the program to exceed the time limit.

You can use `qsort` to reduce the complexity to **O(m*log(m))**.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int compare_ints(const void *a1, const void *a2) {
    const int *p1 = a1;
    const int *p2 = a2;
    return (*p1 > *p2) - (*p1 < *p2);
}

int main() {
    int t;
    if (scanf("%d", &t) != 1)
        return 1;

    while (t-- > 0) {
        int i, n, m;
        if (scanf("%d %d", &n, &m) != 2)
            return 1;

        int a[m];
        int sum = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            if (scanf("%d", &a[i]) != 1)
                return 1;
            sum += a[i];
        }

        if (sum > n) {
            /* all orders cannot be delivered: lets sort the array
             * to determine how many of the lowest orders can be delivered.
             * Optimisation inspired by EdHeal.
             */        
            qsort(t, sizeof(t[0]), m, compare_ints)
            sum = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                sum = sum + a[i];
                if (sum > n)
                    break;
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @EdHeal: I added the optimisation inspired by your comment :)